# How to copy a table and add a field with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, copy, insert-select

I would like to copy a table **A** into a table **B** with `INSERT ... SELECT` without declaring all fields in MySQL.

But the issue is my table B has an auto-increment field at the beginning called `id`:

**table_A**

```
 name    age      etc
-------|--------|--------|
 abc   | 28     | ...    |
```

**table_B**

```
 id      name    age      etc
-------|-------|--------|--------|
```

I tried to do something like:

```
INSERT INTO table_B SELECT auto, * FROM table_A
```

But it didn't work. What is the best solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the column names explicitly:

```
INSERT INTO table_B (name,age,etc) SELECT * FROM table_A
```

or even

```
INSERT INTO table_B (name,age,etc) SELECT name,age,etc FROM table_A
```

Answer (score 0):

You no need to worry to generate a value for id column in Table_B while inserting records from Table_A.

Because `Auto_Incerement` columns are like column which have default value. The difference is only that the default value is increased by some specified interval from the last inserted value in that column.